# Caesar's cipher

Tags: string-manipulation

How can [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) be implemented? I want to use `StringReplace`  but I don't know how to write the replacement rule to replace the characters with, say, the character two positions down in the alphabet.

Comment: Many cipher related functions are available at the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/search/?i=cipher).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
rule[n_] := With[{a = CharacterRange["a", "z"]}, Thread[a -> RotateLeft[a,n]]]

res = StringJoin[StringSplit["hello", ""] /. rule[2]]
```

> "jgnnq"

```
StringJoin[StringSplit[res, ""] /. Reverse /@ rule[2]]
```

> "hello"

Or to follow the example in the *Wikipedia* page:

```
StringJoin[StringSplit[CharacterRange["a", "z"], ""] /. rule[-3]]
```

> "xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw"

Comment: `Rule @@@ Thread[{a, RotateLeft[a, n]}]` is simpler as `Thread[a -> RotateLeft[a,n]]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Indeed thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

This answer is just a complement to Öskå's, showing off the new operator forms introduced in v10.  For compatibility with earlier versions, see his answer.

```
az = CharacterRange["a", "z"];
```

Notice the use of `ReplaceAll` with a single argument to construct a replacing operator:

```
encode = ReplaceAll@Dispatch@Thread[az -> RotateLeft[az, 13]];

StringJoin@encode@Characters["secret message"]
(* "frperg zrffntr" *)

StringJoin@encode@Characters[%]
(* "secret message" *)
```

Comment: @Öskå yes, it needs v10.

Comment: Nice use of new operator form of `ReplaceAll` +1

Comment: Better still, `encode = ReplaceAll@AssociationThread[az, RotateLeft[az, 13]]`

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to express the transformation rules for `StringReplace` would be to write them explicitly (here using the traditional Caesar Cipher three-character shift):

```
StringReplace["THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG"
, { "A"->"X","B"->"Y","C"->"Z","D"->"A","E"->"B"
  , "F"->"C","G"->"D","H"->"E","I"->"F","J"->"G"
  , "K"->"H","L"->"I","M"->"J","N"->"K","O"->"L"
  , "P"->"M","Q"->"N","R"->"O","S"->"P","T"->"Q"
  , "U"->"R","V"->"S","W"->"T","X"->"U","Y"->"V"
  , "Z"->"W"
  }
]

(* QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD *)
```

To avoid the tedium of writing such rules, we could create them programatically from paired substitutions:

```
$encipher =
  Rule ~MapThread~ Characters @ {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW"}

(* 
{A->X,B->Y,C->Z,D->A,E->B,F->C,G->D,H->E,I->F,J->G,K->H,L->I,M->J,
 N->K,O->L,P->M,Q->N,R->O,S->P,T->Q,U->R,V->S,W->T,X->U,Y->V,Z->W}
*)

StringReplace["THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG", $encipher]

(* QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD *)
```

The reverse transformation is then easily computed:

```
$decipher = Reverse /@ $encipher;

StringReplace["QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD", $decipher]

(* THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG *)
```

This scheme is simple, and supports arbitrary substitutions beyond simple shifts.  But since a Caesar Cipher *is* a simple shift, we could define the transformation algorithmically instead:

```
StringReplace["THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG"
, c_ /; OrderedQ[{"A", c, "Z"}] :>
    FromCharacterCode[Mod[ToCharacterCode@c - 65 - 3, 26] + 65]
]

(* QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD *)
```

This subtracts three from the character code of each letter, wrapping around *A* back to *Z*.  The condition `/; OrderedQ[...]` ensures that only the letters are affected.  Spaces are unchanged, as are all other characters that are not Latin letters (we can quibble about whether Caesar knew about J or U on another StackExchange site :).

We could express the shift in a helper function, adding support for both encryption and decryption along the way:

```
$a = ToCharacterCode @ "A";

shift[n_, c_] /; OrderedQ[{"A", c, "Z"}] :=
  FromCharacterCode[Mod[ToCharacterCode@c - $a + n, 26] + $a]

shift[_, c_] := c
```

Again, only the letters from A to Z are changed and other characters are left untouched:

```
shift[-3, "A"]
(* X *)

shift[3, "X"]
(* A *)

shift[3, "!"]
(* ! *)
```

The `StringReplace` expression becomes very simple when using `shift`:

```
StringReplace["HI GLENN STOP GOT GOOD STUFF FOR YOU STOP SIGNED ED", c_ :> shift[-3, c]]

(* EF DIBKK PQLM DLQ DLLA PQRCC CLO VLR PQLM PFDKBA BA *)
```

The function supports deciphering by specifying an opposite shift:

```
StringReplace["EF DIBKK PQLM DLQ DLLA PQRCC CLO VLR PQLM PFDKBA BA", c_ :> shift[3, c]]

(* HI GLENN STOP GOT GOOD STUFF FOR YOU STOP SIGNED ED *)
```

Comment: Nice to see that you respect the UPPERCASE and the `3` - +1 despite the `J`, `U` and `W` :)

Answer (score 1):

Insert the passage you want shifting as a string:

```
str = HELLO WORLD
```

Then, define this function:

```
f[x_] := If[64 < x < 91, (Mod[x - 65 + s, 26] + 65), x]
```

Where `s` is your shift (positive or negative).

Then, simply map the function over the character codes of your string:

```
FromCharacterCode[Map[f, ToCharacterCode[str]]]
```

This will result in a Caeser Shift of `s` from Upper case letters to Upper case letters, without altering the punctuation.

(To change Upper case letters to lower case, or the other way round, simply replace the correspodning `65` with `97`.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
CaeserCipher[s_String, lshift_Integer] := 
 Module[{lc = Alphabet[], uc = ToUpperCase@Alphabet[]},
  encoder = 
   Thread[lc -> RotateLeft[lc, lshift]]~Join~
    Thread[uc -> RotateLeft[uc, lshift]];
  (*Echo[encoder];*)
  Lookup[encoder, #, #] & /@ Characters@s // StringJoin
  ]

str = "The quick brown fox jumped OVER the LAZY dog";
secret = CaeserCipher[str, 23]
```

> "Qeb nrfzh yoltk clu grjmba LSBO qeb IXWV ald"

This can be deciphered if one knows the key (`-23` or `3`):

```
CaeserCipher[secret, -23]
```

> "The quick brown fox jumped OVER the LAZY dog"

---

But what if the key is not known? The following function checks all shifts and selects the one for which the majority of the deciphered words satisfy the  `DictionaryWordQ` predicate. Examples are borrowed from other answers on the page with thanks.

```
CaeserDecipher[secret_String] := CaeserCipher[secret
  , Scan[If[
         Majority @@ (DictionaryWordQ /@ 
            StringSplit@CaeserCipher[secret, #]), Sow@#, Nothing] &
       , Range@Length@Alphabet[]] // Reap // Last // First // First
  ]

s1 = "EF DIBKK PQLM DLQ DLLA PQRCC CLO VLR PQLM PFDKBA BA";
s2 = "Qeb nrfzh yoltk clu grjmba LSBO qeb IXWV ald";
s3 = "uqog tcpfqo vgzv";
s4 = "Vjcqnvjcrlj rb odw";

CaeserDecipher /@ {s1, s2, s3, s4} // Column
```

[image]

Comment: In Roman times, lower case letters were not used. I don't know if they used spaces. More work would be required to decipher messages without spaces.